# How to accept multiple class parameter in a function to create button in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new in javascript. I'm trying to create button like this.

```
<button class="btn btn-info fa fa-check"></button>
```

Here is my javascript function and it works

```
function createButton(buttonTypeClass, eventListener) {
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.classList.add(buttonTypeClass, "btn", "btn-info", "fa");
    button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        eventListener(event);
    });
    return button;
}

......

function createCheckButton() {
    return createButton("fa-check", function(event) {
        addBookToCompleted(event.target.parentElement);
    });
}
```

But what I want defining class of btn-info (from createButton function) inside createCheckButton function coz I wanna make another style button (e.g. createTrashButton with class btn-danger).

```
function createCheckButton() {
    return createButton("btn-info", "fa-check", function(event) {
        addBookToCompleted(event.target.parentElement);
    });
}
```

And it doesn't work well. It's only accept the first class (btn-info). How to fix this?

Comment: Functions have array like `arguments` object. So you can access all the arguments like `arguments[0]`, `arguments[1]` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would pass in an array of classes you want included on the button. This would be functionally correct.

```
function createButton(buttonTypeClasses, eventListener) {
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    buttonTypeClasses.forEach((class) => button.classList.add(class));
    button.classList.add("btn", "fa");
    button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        eventListener(event);
    });
    return button;
}

function createCheckButton() {
    return createButton(["btn-info", "fa-check"], function(event) {
        addBookToCompleted(event.target.parentElement);
    });
}
```

If you want to use the old `function` syntax, the `forEach` line would look like this.

`buttonTypeClasses.forEach(function(class) { button.classList.add(class); });`

Comment: Thank you so much for ur help. Actually here is the code that I wish, but ur code buttonTypeClasses.forEach((class) => button.classList.add(class)); show me a red line. What's wrong?

Comment: Without knowing what the red line means, usually found by hovering over it, I can't help. Possibly use the old function syntax, as shown in the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the function `createButton()` only accepts two params but instead you gave it three params. Try using two params for the class names and one more for the event like

```
createButton(btnClass, btnClass2, eventListener) {
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    // do your thing here
    return button;
}
```

Another solution would be using the arguments array to pass a variable number of params

```
createButton() {
    // arguments array contains all of the params you want to pass and its variable
    // do your thing here
    return button;
}
```

Here's an example I put together to explains `arguments` usage

```
function test() {
    console.log(arguments) // prints all of the values you passed to it
}
test(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for ur answer, it works when I follow ur suggestion using 3 params